# Error al hacer requests en Railway

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoatlas

hice una API con Express y Mongo Atlas. Lo probe de forma local (localhost:3000/administradores) y funciona correctamente. Pero debido a que esto es parte de un proyecto en equipo quise utilizar Railway para que mis compañeros tambien puedieran utilizarla. Subi el proyecto a un repositorio en GitHub y cree el proyecto en Railway y todo perfecto.
El problema es que no puedo hacer un GET para obtener datos de una coleccion (administradores), me aparece el erorr HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
Pero en el deploy log de Railway dice que se conectó correctamente a MongoDB. También cabe decir que en Mongo Atlas, en Network Access están permitidas todas. ¿Cual podrá ser el error?

[VSCode - Request and Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpL0R.png)

[Railway Error Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LS2bM.png)

[Railway - Deploy Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RErL4.png)

[MongoDB Compass - Coleccion Administrador](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WeAK.png)

También debo decir que es mi primera vez usando todo esto (NodeJS, Mongo, Railway) así que el error podría ser algo muy tonto. Pero agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. El código, incluyendo mensajes de error, debes incluirlo en tu pregunta en formato texto y no como imagen y mucho menos como enlaces externos. Haz clic en [edit] y cambia lo que haga falta. Saludos